# Reference request on the generalization of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

As the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, I mean

> Let $[a,b]$ be an interval, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists a polynomial $P$ on $[a,b]$ s.t. $d_{\infty}(P,f)\leq\varepsilon$, where $d_{\infty}$ is the sup metric.

I'd like to know if there is a generalization of such theorem where $f:[0,1]^{n}\to[0,1]^{n}$. If so, could someone tell me where I can find it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some history: The version of the theorem you quote is the simplest one, which was originally proved by Weierstrass in the 1880s. In the 1930s, Stone proved a much more general version. It includes the version you want. (Wikipedia does a decent job explaining the history.)